# regarding converting 1D to 2D in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Given a one dimensional data, how to re-shape it to 2D matrix so that I can leverage the existing 2D convolution in tensorflow?

Comment: Could you elaborate more - on what is the nature of your data, its shape, model details, etc.?

Comment: Use [`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) to change the shape of your tensors.

Comment: @Marcin, I would like to perform some convolution/deconvolution over the one D discrete signal by leveraging the existing conv2d function.

Answer (score 1):

I have to assume that you are talking about an array.  If that is correct then you should be able to convert it using reshape.

from the tensorflow site
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape